# Is it possible to bind two knockout functions to a single button click

Tags: html, knockout.js

I have two knockout JS function and I am trying to call both the functions on a single button click. 
My knockout functions are

```
self.done = function (canadiancrude) {           
        var payload = {
            Id: canadiancrude.Id, Term: canadiancrude.Term(), Product: canadiancrude.Product, Location: canadiancrude.Location(), Pipeline: canadiancrude.Pipeline()
        };
        $.ajax({
            url: '/odata/Canadiancrudes(' + canadiancrude.Id + ')',
            type: 'PUT',
            data: JSON.stringify(payload),
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'json'
        });
    }

self.add = function (pipeline) {
        var payload = { PipelineName: this.Pipeline()};
        $.ajax({
            url: '/odata/Pipelines',
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify(payload),
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'json'

        });

    }
```

I am trying to call both done and add functions on a single button

my HTML is as follows

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-bind="click: done" value="Add New Entry" />
```

**Is it possible?**

Answer (score 3):

You can actually write a function inline in your bindings and call both methods from in there:

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-bind="click: function() { done(); add(); }" value="Add New Entry" />
```

Comment: data-bind="click: function() { done(); add(); }"

I tried this in one of my requirement but this fires the event on page load without clicking on the button which wasn't required.

wrapping it inside event binding is much better option 

event: { click : function() { done(); add(); } }

Comment: he's right. if you do data-bind="click: done(); add()" you will see that behavior, but not the way he wrote it. i'd try again and double check for typos.